# On which JBOSS EAP versions are JBPM7 running

Tags: jboss-eap-6, redhat-bpm

Our company need to decide to go with JBPM6.5-FInal or JBPM7-FINAL
I can't find documentation to indicate on which version of JBOSS EAP will JBPM7 run

Currently we're running JBOSS EAP 6.4 and are not planning to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

jBPM 7.0 - 7.6 was targeting EAP 7.0.x.  jBPM 7.7 will be targeting EAP 7.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

jBPM 7 is not yet productized  by Red Hat and because of that no documentation is available on which EAP version we should deploy jBPM7. But I am able to deploy jBPM 7.4 on top of EAP 7.0.x release. So you can go with this release or you can give a try with EAP 7.1 release.